# Bootstrap, Modal is always show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, modal-dialog, jcrop

I'm following DevsBrasil' [Laravel tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4cWAwUGAvc), trying to crop user image.

and modal is always show..

**This is a controller**:

```
public function editUsers($userID) {

    $user = Sentry::findUserById($userID);

    $data = array();
    $data['image'] = Session::get('img');
    $data['modal'] = (Session::get('modal') == null ? 'false' : 'true');

    $group_p = $user->getGroups();

    $groups_p = [];
    foreach (Sentry::findAllGroups() as $group) {
        $groups_p [$group->id] = $group->name; 
    }

    return View::make('dashboard.users.edit')
    ->with('user',$user)
    ->with('group_p',$group_p)
    ->with('groups_p',$groups_p)
    ->with('data',$data);

}

public function updateUsers($userID) {

    $user = Sentry::findUserById($userID);


    return View::make('dashboard.users.edit')
    ->with('user',$user);
}

public function UploadImg($userID)
{
    if (Input::hasFile('image')) {

    $user = Sentry::findUserById($userID);

    $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $image = Input::file('image');
            $filename  = $user->username . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = public_path('img/users/' . $filename);
            $int_image = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

            $int_image->resize(568,null, function($constraint){
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });

            $int_image->save($path);
            $user->image = 'img/users/'.$filename;

            Session::put('modal','ture');
    }else{
    }

        return Redirect::back();

}

public function CropImg()
{
        return Redirect::back();
}
```

**View :**

```
<!-- Tab content -->
                        <div id="tabImage" class="tab-pane innerAll">
                            <h4 class="innerTB">
                                Update {{ $user->name }} image. 
                            </h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 ">
<div class="bootbox modal fade in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Crop Image</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            {{Form::open(array('route' => 'crop_user_image_post', 'onsubmit' => 'return checkCoords' ,'class'=>'form-horizontal'))}}
            {{HTML::image($data['image'], '' , ['id' => 'crop'] )}}
            <input type="hidden" id="src" name="src" value="{{ $data['image'] }}" >
            <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
            <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
            <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-bb-handler="Done" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success!</button>
         </div>
         {{ Form::close() }}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
{{Form::open(array('route' => 'update_user_image_post', 'method' => 'post','files'=>'true','class'=>'form-horizontal') , $user->id)}}
{{ HTML::image($user->img, $user->username, array('class' => 'img-circle' )) }}
{{Form::file('image')}}
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Image <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
   </div>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
<input type="hidden" id="modal" value="{{$data['modal']}}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- // Tab content END -->
```

**JS Code :**

> I give input hidden with id ( #modal ) value from controller 
>       `$data['modal'] = (Session::get('modal') == null ? 'false' : 'true');`

```
<script>
   var modal;
   if ($('#modal').val() == 'true' ) {
      modal = true;
   }else{
      modal = false;
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#crop').Jcrop({
         aspectRatio: 1,
         onSelect: atualizaCoordenadas
      });
      $('#myModal').modal({show: modal});
   });

   function atualizaCoordenadas(c){
      $('#x').val(c.x);
      $('#y').val(c.y);
      $('#w').val(c.w);
      $('#h').val(c.h);
   }

   function checkCoords(){
      if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
      alert('Error');
      return false;
   }

</script>
```

Comment: First thing you should do is check what the value of "modal" is. Do a `console.log(modal)` to check the console if it is true or false.

Comment: @Gohn67 can you explain what you mean with code, I don't what I must to do ,,

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to use Chrome's Developer console here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console. In your javascript file, type `console.log(modal)` right after the `IF statement`.

Comment: @Gohn67 if you mean it '   if ($('#modal').val() == 'true' ) {
      modal = true;
   }else{
      modal = false;
   }

   console.log(modal)'
Still modal show

Comment: Yes. Check the console to see the value of "modal". Alternatively do `alert(modal)` Basically if you get `true`, then the modal will show.

Comment: It's a false, now what I must to fix it.

Comment: Not sure. It should not show show if it is false. Try removing this line: `$('#myModal').modal({show: modal});` and seeing what happens.

Comment: @Gohn67 Still Showing :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the why the modal keeps showing.

You have `style="display:block"` set in your modal div. Inline styles take precedence over other css styles. I haven't looked at the Bootstrap source, but it's possible the modal visibility is set with a css class instead of inline style.

See here (scroll to the far-right end):

```
<div class="bootbox modal fade in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
```

You need to remove `style="display:block"` from the div like here:

```
<div class="bootbox modal fade in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Here is a more readable version of the div attributes for you to compare:

**Incorrect version**

```
<div 
  class="bootbox modal fade in" 
  id="myModal" 
  tabindex="-1" 
  role="dialog" 
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" 
  aria-hidden="true" 
  style="display: block;"> <!--The issue is this `style` attribute-->
```

**Correct version**

```
<div 
  class="bootbox modal fade in" 
  id="myModal" 
  tabindex="-1" 
  role="dialog" 
  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" 
  aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Ok it's now hidden, but if it's 'true' still hidden. I checked 'modal' by using alert(modal), it's a true

Comment: Did you add back this line here: `$('#myModal').modal({show: modal});`?

Comment: Can you move the alert after that this line `$('#myModal').modal({show: modal})`? Alternatively, change it to `$('#myModal').modal({show: true})` to make sure it works.

Comment: I've try it in advance. And still hidden :/ I'm tired.

Comment: Yeah that's strange. Do you have the `bootstrap.js` file included? If so, you may have an error that's preventing your code from executing. You can check the Chrome/Firefox/IE developer consoles to check

Comment: ^In regards to the previous comment, I mean "If not, you mean have..." Sorry if that caused confusion.